# Are there better ways to split arrays into smaller arrays?

Tags: vb.net, linq, skip, take

I have a program that will create orders for a bunch of orders. However API has limitation that if I wanna do that I got to do it 10 at a time

```
If orderList.Count > 10 Then
    Dim FirstTwenty = From n In orderList Take (10)
    Dim theRest = From n In orderList Skip (10)
    Dim result1 = Await internalActualcreateNormalLimitOrderMultiple(FirstTwenty.ToArray)
    Dim result2 = Await internalActualcreateNormalLimitOrderMultiple(theRest.ToArray)
    Return result1 + result2 'no longer json but we don't really use the resulting json unless for debugging
End If
```

Basically I want to split {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.11.12,...} into {1,2,3}{4,5,6},{7,8,9},...

And I wonder if I can use linq instead of for each

So I use this recursive function. Get first 10 or twenty and then recursively call the function and so on.

And I look at it and while it's simple, it doesn't seem right. Obviously number of orders won't be big. At most 15. But what about if on day I have 100? I can get like stackoverflow for recursive things.

If only there is a function that can split arrays into array using linq, where, take, and skip that'll be great.

Of course I can do for each but perhaps there is a more elegant way?

Then I wrote another code

```
Public Shared Function splitArrayIntoSmallerArrays(Of someObject)(arrayOfSomeObject As someObject(), chunkSize As Integer) As List(Of someObject())
    Dim output = New List(Of someObject())
    Dim newestArray = New List(Of someObject)
    For i = 0 To arrayOfSomeObject.Count - 1

        newestArray.Add(arrayOfSomeObject(i))
        If newestArray.Count = chunkSize Then
            output.Add(newestArray.ToArray)
            newestArray = New List(Of someObject)
        End If
    Next
    output.Add(newestArray.ToArray)
    Return output
End Function
```

That'll do it in O(n)

But I think it can be done more simply by using linq, seek, and take but I don't know how. Or may be group by.

Any idea?

Comment: I have read and reread your post about three times and I still don't fully understand what it is that you want to do. Could you give an example of the data you want back?

Comment: You can use a While loop, set a variable that stores the number of items to take (instead of just hard-coding`10`), store the increment, skip the increment (starts from `0`), take the number of items, call the method (once) and use another variable to sum the results

Comment: What is wrong with a for loop, which adds the items into a smaller array with a counter that counts to 10?  Once 10 is hit the API gets called, counter reset and the smaller array cleared.  All you need to make sure is the that API is called also at the end with any rump array.

Comment: I've been thinking that doing for each is not that bad. I should just use for each.

Basically I want to split {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.11.12,...} into {1,2,3}{4,5,6},{7,8,9},...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a collection into n parts with LINQ, in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847591/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq-in-vb-net)

Comment: Yes. Much more complicated than I thought but I will look into it

Answer (score 1):

Your question was not very clear to me, but I believe you have an array with several "objects" inside it, correct? And before that you want to divide this matrix into smaller matrices, correct?

So how about passing this larger matrix to a JSON, creating an object that will be filled in by the smaller values ​​and then transforming this JSON again into objects of the type above, then passing these objects to the smaller array, do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Net 7.0, perhaps you're looking for [Enumerable.Chunk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-7.0)?

`Splits the elements of a sequence into chunks of size at most size.`

Comment: Wow. How do I know I have that? How to upgrade to Net 7.0